# Как передавать объекты класса в другой класс?

Tags: python, классы

У меня есть класс PatientsCard, который описывает медицинскую карту пациента. Также у меня есть класс Polyclinic. Конструктор класса Polyclinic должен принимать на вход объекты класса PatientsCard и хранить эти объекты в списке. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно передавать объекты одного класса в другой и в дальнейшем иметь возможность получать доступ к полям переданного объекта.

```
#Класс описывающий медицинскую карту пациента

class PatientsCard:
def __init__(self, name, surname, address=None, insurance=0):
    self.__name = name
    self.__surname = surname
    self.__address = address
    self.__insurance = insurance

@property
def name(self):
    return self.__name

@name.setter
def name(self, name):
    if type(name) == str and len(name) > 1:
        self.__name = name
    else:
        print('Invalid name has been entered!')

@property
def surname(self):
    return self.__surname

@surname.setter
def surname(self, surname):
    if type(surname) == str and len(surname) > 1:
        self.__surname = surname
    else:
        print('Invalid surname has been entered!')

@property
def address(self):
    return self.__address

@address.setter
def address(self, address):
    if type(address) == str and len(address) > 1:
        self.__address = address
    else:
        print('Invalid address has been entered!')

@property
def insurance(self):
    return self.__insurance

@insurance.setter
def insurance(self, insurance):
    if len(str(insurance)) == 10:
        self.__insurance = int(insurance)
    else:
        print('Invalid insurance number has been entered!')



#Класс куда нужно передать объекты предыдущего класса

class Polyclinic:
def __init__(self, number, address, *args):
    self.__number = number
    self.__address = address
    self.__patients = [args] 

#Модуль Main. Передача объектов
patient1 = PatientsCard('Kirill', 'Kondratyuk', 'Chkalova 11', 1786958694)
patient2 = PatientsCard('Kirrill', 'Kondratyuk', 'Chkalova 12', 7584927688)
polyclinic1 = Polyclinic(7, 'sadasdasd', patient1, patient2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Polyclinic:
    def __init__(self, number, address, *args):
        self.__number = number
        self.__address = address
        self.patients = list(args)

polyclinic1 = Polyclinic(7, 'sadasdasd', patient1, patient2)

print(polyclinic1.patients[0])
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это решает проблему.